# Identify Sequelize model in global hook

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm looking to add some low level logging to all of my Sequelize operations via global hooks. Something like this:

`` db.addHook('beforeUpdate', (instance, options) => {
  log.info({ instance, options }, `Updating ${modelName} ${instance.get('id')}`);
}); ``

What I haven't figured out is how to populate `modelName` or even whether it's possible (although the lack of information I've found is indicative that it may not be possible). Any chance this *is* possible and I just haven't found the key?

As logged, here's the instance value:

`instance: {
  "id": null,
  "nonIncarcerationAgreementIndicator": true,
  "insuranceApplicationId": 22,
  "updatedAt": "2018-06-13T13:55:10.978Z",
  "createdAt": "2018-06-13T13:55:10.978Z"
}`

The `options` are too long to list, but nowhere do they mention the model name.

Comment: Will you please share the output of `instance` and `options` ?

Comment: Added the `instance` output and referenced `options` which is longer than would be useful since it doesn't mention the model name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of sequelize are you on? For v4, this works

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('test_db', 'postgres', 'postgres', {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  dialect: 'postgres',
  define: {
    hooks: {
      beforeCreate: (model, options) => {
        console.log(model.constructor.name);
      }
    }
  }
});
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
});

User.create({
  username: 'UserOne',
  projects: {
    projectName: 'projectOne'
  }
}).then((user) => {
  console.log(user);
})
```